# How to cell background Color change Based on a Value in Excel using node js

Tags: node.js

cell background Color change Based on a Value in Excel using node js
color codes red or green or blue if Value condition
Please share any example or sample code i need export with color codes based on value conditions

Thanks
Shanker.B

Sample example above requirement .